# Execute code using 'Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019' via PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, command-line, tfs, tfvc

There are certain 'tf' commands that only work within 'Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019' (DCP) and not in cmd or PowerShell.

The code I need to run via the DCP will be written dynamically by a Powershell script.

For example, the code could be getting the latest version of files within a folder in DevOps source control. The commands for this would be as follows:

```
cd "C:\someroot\foldername"
tf get
```

When I execute the PowerShell script, it would determine what 'foldername' is required and then create these lines of code. This is a simplified example.

What script do I require to run the code automatically from within the PowerShell using the DCP?

The DCP window is opened from the following:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat

I would welcome any suggestions of how to run either individual lines of code or a batch file direct from a PowerShell script using the DCP (Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019).

**EDIT:**

When I manually open the Developer Command Prompt via the provided shortcut, the window opens with the current directory set to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional. I can successfully change this using the command `cd  "C:\root\folder name"`. The command `tf get` then also works, getting the latest files for files in that folder in source control. I've tried using Start-Process with these commands separated by a semi-colon in -ArgumentList. However, this doesn't work and returns "Invalid command line argument: 'cd'".

**Attempts:**

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -ArgumentList "cd ""C:\root\folder name"" ; tf get" 

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -WorkingDirectory "C:\root\folder name" -ArgumentList "tf get"
```

I added `-RedirectStandardOutput "c:\standardoutput.txt"` to the above commands to record the output.

I also attempted accessing the Developer Command Prompt via the shortcut but couldn't work out how to add code to run commands once the prompt was opened...

```
Invoke-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools\Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019.lnk"
```

Comment: You don't need to use the developer command prompt for `tf`. The executable should be located in `$(Agent.HomeDirectory)\externals\tf\tf.exe`, which you'd probably see if you looked at the `Checkout` step. To ensure the command is running from the appropriate directory, make sure the working directory for the command is set correctly.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for your comment. I have located the executable.. "..\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe". Please may you advise what I do to make use of this in my PowerShell script? I have been back through the Microsoft documentation and can't see anything about how to use this.

Comment: Like I said, set the working directory for the step you're using to run the command. With the details you've provided, that's the best I can offer.

Comment: `VsDevCmd.bat` is adding to the PATH so that the `tf` command can be found. That's all that `VsDevCmd.bat` does with regards to the `tf` command. The `tf get` command requires that the current directory is a TFVC workspace.

Comment: @JonathanDodds @DanielMann thanks. When I manually open the Developer Command Prompt via the provided shortcut, the window opens with the current directory set to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional. I can successfully change this using the command `cd  "C:\root\folder name"`. The command `tf get` then also works, getting the latest files for files in that folder in source control. I've tried using `Start-Process` with these commands separated by a semi-colon in `-ArgumentList`. However, this doesn't work and returns "Invalid command line argument: 'cd'".

Comment: Are you using `cmd` as the executable? Windows Batch doesn't recognize the semi-colon as a command delimiter. If you want multiple commands on one line use `&`, e.g. `cmd0 & cmd1`.

Comment: Instead of performing a `cd` command, use the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlet's [`-WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-workingdirectory) parameter.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanDodds I tried replacing the semi-colon with an ampersand but it still returned the same error. I also tried using the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter, see the second attempt in my updated question content above. However, all my attempts result in the same kind of error: `[ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument: 'cd'. Argument will be ignored.`. When providing the `workingdirectory` it is the `'tf'` that is 'invalid' and 'ignored'. That error also includes: [ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***

Comment: `tf` and `cd` are not valid arguments to `VsDevCmd.bat`.

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c \`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat\`" & tf get" -WorkingDirectory "C:\root\folder name"`

Comment: @JonathanDodds that works! Thank you so much. If you add this as an answer I will accept it. Any added explanation about the `filepath` and `argumentlist` parameter values you've used would be helpful if possible. Very happy to finally have a way of doing this via code! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Start-Process` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) will start an executable. The required [`-FilePath` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-filepath) is the **executable to be run** (or a document file with a file extension that is mapped to an executable). The [`-ArgumentList` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-argumentlist) is arguments to be passed to the executable.

On your system the 'Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019' shortcut is defined as:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

The path for VsDevCmd.bat will vary. For example, I have VS2022 Community on a machine and the path is `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`.

On Windows, the [vswhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere) tool or the [VSSetup](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell) PowerShell module can be used to locate Visual Studio.

`%comspec%` is an environment variable. On current versions of Windows, it is generally set to the path and file name of [`cmd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd).

The Dev Prompt shortcut is running the `cmd.exe` executable with an argument list of `/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`. The `/k` parameter keeps the command shell running after executing a command. In this case the `VsDevCmd.bat` file is executed.

Mapping the shortcut to `Start-Process`, the `-FilePath` would be `"$env:comspec"` and the `-ArgumentList` would be `/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`.

Changing the `/k` to `/c` causes `cmd` to exit after executing the command.

In the Windows batch language, two or more commands can be provided in one line by separating the commands with an `&`. The following will run `tf get` after running the VS batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" & tf get
```

`Start-Process` has a [`-WorkingDirectory` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-workingdirectory) which sets the current directory for the new process.

Bringing this all together looks like the following.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`" & tf get" -WorkingDirectory "C:\root\folder name"
```

(Note that the `-ArgumentList` string is enclosed within double quotes but double quotes are also needed for the 'Program Files (x86)' path. Within the string, double quotes are escaped with a backtick.)

Another approach would be to locate Visual Studio. The `tf.exe` tool will be in a standard location within the Visual Studio installation. If the path and name of `tf.exe` is determined, the `tf` command could be run directly without using the command shell.

Given variables `$Tf` and `$Workspace` for the path and name of `tf` and for the workspace directory, respectively:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$Tf" -ArgumentList "get" -WorkingDirectory "$Workspace"
```

An example value for `$Tf` would be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"`.

An example value for `$Workspace` would be `"C:\root\folder name"`.